# MongoDB explains totalKeysExamined more than limit

Tags: mongodb

I have a very large collection (millions of documents) with data which looks like:

```
u'timestamp': 1481454871423.0,
u'_id': ObjectId('584d351772c4d8106cc43116'),
u'data': {
       ...
    },
u'geocode': [{u'providerId': 2, u'placeId': 97459515},
             {u'providerId': 3, u'placeId': 237},
             {u'providerId': 3, u'placeId': 3}]
```

I want a query which targets a providerId and placeId pair, and returns 10 records only, within a timestamp range.

To that end I perform queries like:

```
 'geocode.providerId': 3,
 'geocode.placeId': 3
 'timestamp': { '$gte': 1481454868360L,
                '$lt': 1481454954839L }
```

And I provide a hint, to target the index which looks like:

```
[('geocode.providerId', 1), ('geocode.placeId', 1), ('timestamp', 1)]
```

where 1 is ascending. Before iterating over the returned cursor, it is **limited to 10 records** and sorted ascending on timestamp (which should be it's default state due to the index).

A pymongo query looks like:

```
collection.find(findDic).hint(hint).sort([('timestamp', pymongo.ASCENDING)]).skip(0).limit(10)
```

The query explains come back looking like:

```
{
u'executionStats': {
    u'executionTimeMillis': 1270,
    u'nReturned': 10,
    u'totalKeysExamined': 568686,
    u'allPlansExecution': [],
    u'executionSuccess': True,
    u'executionStages': {
        u'needYield': 0,
        u'saveState': 4442,
        u'memUsage': 54359,
        u'restoreState': 4442,
        u'memLimit': 33554432,
        u'isEOF': 1,
        u'inputStage': {
            u'needYield': 0,
            u'saveState': 4442,
            u'restoreState': 4442,
            u'isEOF': 1,
            u'inputStage': {
                u'needYield': 0,
                u'docsExamined': 284964,
                u'saveState': 4442,
                u'restoreState': 4442,
                u'isEOF': 1,
                u'inputStage': {
                    u'saveState': 4442,
                    u'isEOF': 1,
                    u'seenInvalidated': 0,
                    u'keysExamined': 568686,
                    u'nReturned': 284964,
                    u'invalidates': 0,
                    u'keyPattern': {u'geocode.providerId': 1,
                            u'timestamp': 1,
                            u'geocode.placeId': 1},
                    u'isUnique': False,
                    u'needTime': 283722,
                    u'isMultiKey': True,
                    u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 360,
                    u'dupsTested': 568684,
                    u'restoreState': 4442,
                    u'direction': u'forward',
                    u'indexName': u'geocode.providerId_1_geocode.placeId_1_timestamp_1',
                    u'isSparse': False,
                    u'advanced': 284964,
                    u'stage': u'IXSCAN',
                    u'dupsDropped': 283720,
                    u'needYield': 0,
                    u'isPartial': False,
                    u'indexBounds': {u'geocode.providerId': [u'[3, 3]'
                            ],
                            u'timestamp': [u'[-inf.0, 1481455513378)'
                            ],
                            u'geocode.placeId': [u'[MinKey, MaxKey]'
                            ]},
                    u'works': 568687,
                    u'indexVersion': 1,
                    },
                u'nReturned': 252823,
                u'needTime': 315863,
                u'filter': {u'$and': [{u'geocode.placeId': {u'$eq': 3}},
                            {u'timestamp': {u'$gte': 1481405886510L}}]},
                u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 970,
                u'alreadyHasObj': 0,
                u'invalidates': 0,
                u'works': 568687,
                u'advanced': 252823,
                u'stage': u'FETCH',
                },
            u'nReturned': 0,
            u'needTime': 315864,
            u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 1150,
            u'invalidates': 0,
            u'works': 568688,
            u'advanced': 0,
            u'stage': u'SORT_KEY_GENERATOR',
            },
        u'nReturned': 10,
        u'needTime': 568688,
        u'sortPattern': {u'timestamp': 1},
        u'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 1200,
        u'limitAmount': 10,
        u'invalidates': 0,
        u'works': 568699,
        u'advanced': 10,
        u'stage': u'SORT',
        },
    u'totalDocsExamined': 284964,
    },
u'queryPlanner': {
    u'parsedQuery': {u'$and': [{u'geocode.placeId': {u'$eq': 3}},
                     {u'geocode.providerId': {u'$eq': 3}},
                     {u'timestamp': {u'$lt': 1481455513378L}},
                     {u'timestamp': {u'$gte': 1481405886510L}}]},
    u'rejectedPlans': [],
    u'namespace': u'mxp957.tweet_244de17a-aa75-4da9-a6d5-97b9281a3b55',
    u'winningPlan': {
        u'sortPattern': {u'timestamp': 1},
        u'inputStage': {u'inputStage': {u'filter': {u'$and': [{u'geocode.placeId': {u'$eq': 3}},
                        {u'timestamp': {u'$gte': 1481405886510L}}]},
                        u'inputStage': {
            u'direction': u'forward',
            u'indexName': u'geocode.providerId_1_geocode.placeId_1_timestamp_1',
            u'isUnique': False,
            u'isSparse': False,
            u'isPartial': False,
            u'indexBounds': {u'geocode.providerId': [u'[3, 3]'],
                             u'timestamp': [u'[-inf.0, 1481455513378)'
                             ],
                             u'geocode.placeId': [u'[MinKey, MaxKey]'
                             ]},
            u'isMultiKey': True,
            u'stage': u'IXSCAN',
            u'indexVersion': 1,
            u'keyPattern': {u'geocode.providerId': 1,
                            u'timestamp': 1,
                            u'geocode.placeId': 1},
            }, u'stage': u'FETCH'},
                u'stage': u'SORT_KEY_GENERATOR'},
        u'limitAmount': 10,
        u'stage': u'SORT',
        },
    u'indexFilterSet': False,
    u'plannerVersion': 1,
    },
u'ok': 1.0,
u'serverInfo': {
    u'host': u'rabbit',
    u'version': u'3.2.11',
    u'port': 27017,
    u'gitVersion': u'009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4',
    },
}
```

I don't understand why all of these documents need to be examined. In the case above, the size of the collection is only 284587 which means that every record was looked at twice! I want totalKeysExamined to only be 10, but am struggling to see how to achieve this.

I am using MongoDB version 3.2.11 and pymongo.

Comment: Primarily looks the the order of keys passed in query and that of in index Index:geocode.providerId_1_geocode.placeId_1_timestamp_1                            Query: parsedQuery': {u'$and': [{u'geocode.placeId': {u'$eq': 3}},
                     {u'geocode.providerId': {u'$eq': 3}},
                     {u'timestamp': {u'$lt': 1481455513378L}},
                     {u'timestamp': {u'$gte': 1481405886510L}}]}                                         The total number of documents 284964 and totalDocsExamined: 284964, goes to show the index is not being optimally used.

Answer (score 0):

As Astro mentioned, the issue is that MongoDB was not using the index effectively.

MongoDB team say that this is resolved in later versions:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27386

Also an option is to remove providerId from the index. In my use case, providerId is one of two values, and most of the time will always be the same value. It represents which API was used to geocode; my system only supports two, and only has one enabled at any one time.

See the commit that would resolve this:
https://github.com/watfordxp/GeoTweetSearch/commit/420536e4a138fb22e0dd0e61ef9c83c23a9263c1